# Is the integral of a $k$ times differentiable function again $k$ times differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^k\times[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is (at least) continuous, and let $F:\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by integrating out the last variable, i.e.,
$$F(x_1,\dots,x_k)=\int_a^b f(x_1,\dots,x_k,t)\,\text{d}t$$

I'm wondering what one can say about smoothness of $F$, given the degree of smoothness of $f$. Explicitly, **if $f$ is $n$ times continuously differentiable, can one say in general that $F$ is $n$ times continuously differentiable?** I have the feeling that at least *something of the type* must be true, and I'd like to know what exactly that would be. Please also give references to the proof (or the proof itself).

Comment: Since $f$ is differentiable, for each $(x,t)$, there exists a continuously varying matrix $L(x,t)$ and a function $\epsilon$ s.t. $f(x + d, t) = f(x,t) + L(x,t) d + \epsilon(x,t,d)$ where $\frac{\epsilon(x,t,d)}{||d||} \to 0$ with $||d||$ for each $(x,t)$. Consequently, you'll get $F(x+d) - F(x) - \int_a^b L(x,t) d \,\mathrm{d}t = \int_a^b \epsilon(x,d, t) \,\mathrm{d}t$. Show that this last integral goes to $0$ faster than $||d||$, and you'll have shown that $F$ is differentiable. Next show that integrating one coordinate out in $L$ will preserve continuity in other coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going answer my own question, for I think I found a proof of the following theorem.

**Theorem 1.** Let $f:\mathbb{R}^k\times[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function, and let $F:\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by integrating out the last variable, i.e., $F(x_1,\dots,x_k)=\int_a^b f(x_1,\dots,x_k,t)\,\text{d}t$. If $f$ is of class $C^n$ for some $n\geq 1$, then so is $F$.

*Proof.*
Notice first that the function $F$ exists, since $f$ is at least of class $C^1$ and hence continuous in $t$, and hence integrable over $t$.
We'll use Theorem 18.9.1 from the book *A Course in Mathematical Analysis (Part II)* by D.J.H. Garling:

**Theorem 2. (Garling.)**
Suppose that $A$ is a compact Jordan measurable subset of $\mathbb R^k$, that $a<b\in\mathbb R$, and that $g:A\times (a,b)\to E$ is continuous with $E$ a Banach space. Suppose also that $(\partial g/\partial t)(x,t)$ (exists and) is continuous everywhere. Let $G(t)=\int_Af(x,t)\text{d} x$. Then $G$ is continuously differentiable on $(a,b)$ and 
\begin{align*}
\frac{\text{d} G}{\text{d} t}(t)=\int_A\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(x,t)\text{d} x
\end{align*}

The theorem is much more general than we need, so we will use the following corollary, which follows immediately from the theorem. (Notice that we interchange the roles of $x$ and $t$.)

**Corollary 3.**
Suppose that $g:\mathbb R\times[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and has continuous partial derivative $(\partial g/\partial x)(x,t)$. Set $G(x)=\int_a^b g(x,t)\text{d} t$. Then $G$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$ and 
\begin{align*}
\frac{\text{d} G}{\mathbb d x}(x)=\int_a^b\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,t)\text{d} t
\end{align*}

We now have the ingredients to prove Theorem 1. We fix $x_1,\dots,x_{k-1}$, set $g(x_k,t) = f(x_1,\dots,x_k,t)$ and define
\begin{align*}
G(x_k)=\int_a^b g(x_k,t)\text{d} t = \int_a^b f(x_1,\dots,x_k,t) \text{d} t = F(x_1,\dots, x_k)
\end{align*}
Since $f$ is of class $C^k$, $f$ is continuous and $\partial g/\partial x_k$ is continuous. By the corollary, $G$ is  differentiable with
\begin{align*}
\frac{\text{d} G}{\text{d} x_k}(x_k)=\int_a^b\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_k}(x_k,t)\text{d} t
\end{align*}
But by definition of the partial derivative this means precisely that $F$ admits a partial derivative with respect to $x_k$ and that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_k}(x_1,\dots,x_k)=\int_a^b\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}(x_1,\dots,x_k,t)\text{d} t
\end{align*}
Continuity follows from the following. Let $\epsilon>0$. If $U\subset\mathbb R^k$ is an open ball around $0$, then there is a compact set $K$ that contains $U$. Then $K\times[a,b]$ is compact and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}$ is uniformly continuous on this set. Hence there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $|(x_1',\dots,x_k')-(x_1,\dots,x_k)|<\delta$ for $(x_1',\dots,x_k')\in U$ and $(x_1,\dots,x_k)\in U$, then 
\begin{align*}
\bigg|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}(x_1',\dots x_k',t)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}(x_1,\dots,x_k,t)\bigg|<\epsilon/(b-a)
\end{align*}
But then
\begin{align*}
\bigg|\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_k}&(x_1',\dots x_k')-\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_k}(x_1,\dots,x_k)\bigg| \\
%
&= \bigg|\int_a^b\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}(x_1',\dots x_k',t)\text{d} t-\int_a^b\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}(x_1,\dots,x_k,t)\text{d} t\bigg|\\
%
&\leq \int_a^b\bigg|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}(x_1',\dots x_k',t)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}(x_1,\dots,x_k,t)\bigg|\text{d} t \\
%
&<\epsilon/(b-a)\int_a^b\text{d} t = \epsilon
\end{align*}
which shows that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_k}$ is continuous on $U$. But this holds for all open balls $U$ around $0$, and hence $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_k}$ is continuous on $\mathbb R^k$. 
Of course there is nothing special about $x_k$, and indeed, similar arguments show that $F$ admits a continuous partial derivative with respect to $x_i$ with
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}(x_1,\dots,x_k)=\int_a^b\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x_1,\dots,x_k,t)\text{d} t
\end{align*}
for each $i=1,\dots, k$. Since all partial derivatives of $F$ are continuous, $F$ is of class $C^1$. If $n=1$ we are done. Provided $n\geq 2$, we repeat the exact same argument with $g(x_k,t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x_1,\dots,x_k,t)$ (for arbitrary $i$) and 
\begin{align*}
G(x_k)=\int_a^b g(x_k,t)\text{d} t = \int_a^b \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x_1,\dots,x_k,t) \text{d} t = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}(x_1,\dots, x_k)
\end{align*}
The same argument is again possible because $g$ is continuous and $\partial g/\partial t$ is as well, as $f$ is now at least of class $C^2$. If we also realize again that $x_k$ is not special, it follows that $\partial F/\partial x_i$ admits a continuous partial derivative with respect to $x_j$, for all $j$, and that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(x_1,\dots,x_k)=\int_a^b\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(x_1,\dots,x_k,t)\text{d} t
\end{align*}
for all $i,j=1,\dots, k$. Hence $F$ is of class $C^2$. If $n=2$ we are done, and if $n>2$ we can continue in this way, repeating the same argument with the obvious choices for the function $g$. It thus follows that $F$ admits all partial derivatives of order $n$, and that these are all continuous, which means that $F$ is of class $C^n$, as was to be shown. Q.E.D.

**Remark.** The proof also shows that the partial derivatives of $F$ are obtained by `differentiating under the integral sign'.